# Filtering by year in a Large List of dataframes

Tags: r, list, filter, dplyr, lapply

I have a large list of dataframes, and I would like to filter the list in the dataframe by a specific year.

DateAndTime is a column that contains Y-M-D H:M:S, and I would like to filter the list of dataframes by only the year.

```
plot_list %>% lapply(dplyr::filter(plot_list, format(DateAndTime, "%Y") == year))
```

I have tried to use lapply on the list, but it doesn't appear to be working. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are looping over `plot_list`, we don't need the `plot_list` again on `filter`.  In `base R`, this can be done using `subset`

```
plot_list_sub <- lapply(plot_list, subset,
           subset = format(DateAndTime, "%Y") == year)
```

Or using `lambda/anonymous` function

```
plot_list_sub <- lapply(plot_list, function(x) 
        subset(x, format(DateAndTime, "%Y") == year))
```

---

Or if we want `tidyverse`, loop over the `list` with `map` (from `purrr`) and use `filter` on the `list` element.  Here, we use a lambda function (`~`) with `.x` being the element in that `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
plot_list_sub <- map(plot_list, ~ .x %>%
                      filter(format(DateAndTime, "%Y") == year))
```